# MVC5 Controller not receiving JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a controller with method as follows:

```
public JsonResult Save(List<BlogInfo> list)
{
    return Json(new { Data = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And I have an ajax post from the client as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Save",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: ko.mapping.toJSON(ViewModel),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.Status);
    }
});
```

My problem is that list parameter to the controller is always null. I tried changing it to string instead of List but that is also null.

Using Fiddler, I can see that the JSON is being pass as follows:

```
{"Data":[{"Id":1,"Title":"Sudoku Solver","Description":"Programmed Sudoku Solver","Tags":["programming","sudoku"]},{"Id":2,"Title":"Picnic","Description":"Went to millpoint","Tags":["picnic"]},{"Id":0,"Title":"Title","Description":"Description","Tags":[]}]}
```

Comment: Please post hows look your `data`

Comment: What does `ko.mapping.toJSON(ViewModel)` generate ? Post it

Comment: This is what I get using Fiddler: `{"Data":[{"Id":1,"Title":"Sudoku Solver","Description":"Programmed Sudoku Solver","Tags":["programming","sudoku"]},{"Id":2,"Title":"Picnic","Description":"Went to millpoint","Tags":["picnic"]},{"Id":0,"Title":"Title","Description":"Description","Tags":[]}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you have shown doesn't represent an array, so you cannot possibly expect to bind it to a list on the server. To achieve that make sure that you are sending an array of objects from the client:

```
data: ko.mapping.toJSON(ViewModel.Data);
```

Here we take the `ViewModel.Data` property which represents an array so that we send only the desired JSON:

```
[{"Id":1,"Title":"Sudoku Solver","Description":"Programmed Sudoku Solver","Tags":["programming","sudoku"]},{"Id":2,"Title":"Picnic","Description":‌​"Went to millpoint","Tags":["picnic"]},{"Id":0,"Title":"Title","Description":"Description‌​","Tags":[]}]
```